# How to refer to pages: at / on / in?

Tags: prepositions

When talking about pages, which preposition is correct, at / on / in?

> This subject starts **at / on / in** p. 55 and ends **at / on / in** p. 65.

Comment: We usually say _on_ a page, but I think _starts at p.55_ would be acceptable.

Comment: I would add that "starts at / ends at" is the minimum amount of information (should I read p. 65?). However "starts on / ends on" gives a little more detail (I should read p.65). Compare that to someone who wants to give a lot of detail with "It starts in the middle of p.55 and ends three quarters into p. 65." (thank you helpful person!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *starts **at*** - locational metaphor - ***at*** some position (offset from the start) in a book
> *starts **on*** - surface metaphor - ***on*** some (flat) page in a book
> *starts **in*** - container metaphor - somewhere ***within*** a page (that also contains other text)

All three prepositions are "valid", but ***in*** is relatively unlikely with ***page*** (it's more likely with a *larger* "containing space", such as ***chapter***).

There's no doubt that *starts **on** page N* is by far the most common choice. Probably because when reading a book we spend most of our time looking at the flat surface of each page, rather than moving through "locations" as we turn pages. But other ways of looking at things are perfectly okay (including *starts **from** page N*, seen as the metaphorical "departure point" for a brief ["foray"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/foray) into the textbook).